# Is it possible to create Sharepoint online APP which will provide new REST API End Points

Tags: office365, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-apps

We are working on sharepoint online integration with PHP Based application. We need to provide REST API call which supports JSONP. So is it possible to create new REST API Endpoints in Sharepoint online APP? Please sugggest right direction.

Comment: do you need to secure this API via the identity provided by SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can perfectly develop a PHP Provider-hosted app/add-in for SharePoint. And then the limit is only about what you can do with PHP.
Here is a sample on how to do that [git hub office dev sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PHP-App-for-SharePoint)